# Accessing Google Sheets API through a service account impersonating a user through domain-wide delegation fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-oauth, service-accounts

### Example code

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account 
import pygsheets

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'my/path/to/credentials.json',
    scopes=('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'),
    subject='account@mydomain.com'
)
pg = pygsheets.authorize(custom_credentials=creds)
pg.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/my_spreadsheet_id/edit#gid=my_sheet_id')
```

### Problematic behaviour

Fails on the last line with `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.`

### Expected behaviour

The last line provides an object for Google Sheets access.

### Additional info

- Domain-wide delegation is enabled for the service account, `subject` account is on the domain
- Sheet is shared with the `subject` account
- When I don't provide the `subject` and share the sheet with the service account directly, it works

**Environment**

- `python==3.6.9`
- `pygsheets==2.0.3.1`
- `google-auth==1.6.3`

Comment: If your request works without subject, but fails with it - most likely you did not enable the necessary scopes for domain-wide delegation in the admin console under `Security - > API constrols`, see [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/162106?hl=en).
@TheMaster: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @ziganotschka This was indeed the case. Would you care to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To consider when using domain-wide delegation

The domain-wide delegation is not enabled by default. To allow it you need to follow the steps described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account).

1. Step: in the GCP console:

- You need to activate the checkbox `Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation` for each service account you want to use for such purpose
  To you use the service account to impersonate a user, you need to give the necessary permissions in the Admin console

2. In the Admin console:

- Any scopes that the service account needs when impersonating a user have to be authorized in the admin console
- For this go to `Main menu menu> Security > API controls.`
- Add (if not already done) the service account of interest by its `Client ID`, provide it all the scopes it needs and authorize
- You can modify the scopes anytime at a later stage if needed